# Displaying Custom Post Type on page

Tags: wordpress

I am having a constant problem with my custom post type I have looking up different way  to display my custom post type but nothing but a blank page and previous post and next post is  displayed I have registered the custom post type as displayed below.

```
    function Memberss() {
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Members', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Member', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Member', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Members', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Members', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Members', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Member', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'New Member', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Member', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Member', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Members', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'No Members found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'No Members found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'Member',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Members', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Member information pages', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'query_var'           => 'Member',
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'Members', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'Memberss', 0 );
```

Please can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5):

To display custom posts, use the following code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'Members', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: Does this code need to be placed on single.php or archive.php

Comment: If Have you created page for display custom post, then it is better to create page template for that and place code into page template.

Comment: I forgot to tell you I also have custom fields in the post types is  i possible to display them as well. thanks

Comment: what I meant was as well the custom post list is it possible to display the all fields in custom post on a page.

Comment: Advanced custom field

Comment: Read this doc http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/ it will help you how to get value of custom field.

Comment: its important to use wp_reset_postdata(); to [reset your post data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata), else yuo may have bizarre errors in the execution of the rest of the page which will be very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your post before the loop

```
 <?php 
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
   $loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'Members'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'paged'          => $paged,

    )); 
  ?>
```

To display your custom fields use

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'META_BOX_ID_HERE', true); ?>
```